# cryptoJS deciphering/decrypting messages AES CFB mode

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs

I am encrypting some string in Ruby, sending it to a client and attempting to decrypt the string there. I am not using the aes rollup (though I have tried with the same result). I have included the aes.js, core.js and cipher-core.js packages as assets. I have checked that the function that is reported as not found does exist in cipher-core.js. I am getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDecryptor' of undefined
at Object.reset (aes.self-9251f7d….js?body=1:28)
at Object.init (aes.self-9251f7d….js?body=1:25)
at Object.c.hasOwnProperty.c.init (aes.self-9251f7d….js?body=1:8)
at Object.c.hasOwnProperty.c.init (aes.self-9251f7d….js?body=1:8)
at Object.c.hasOwnProperty.c.init (aes.self-9251f7d….js?body=1:8)
at Object.create (aes.self-9251f7d….js?body=1:8)
at Object.createDecryptor (aes.self-9251f7d….js?body=1:25)
at Object.decrypt (aes.self-9251f7d….js?body=1:31)
at Object.decrypt (aes.self-9251f7d….js?body=1:32)
at Object.decrypt (aes.self-9251f7d….js?body=1:26)
```

Here is the code:

```
function decipher(encipheredMessage, password, iv) {
  var parts = encipheredMessage.split('--', 2),
      enciphered = replaceHex(parts[0])

  deciphered = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
    enciphered,
    password,
    { iv: iv,
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB,
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding }
    ).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)

  return deciphered
}
```

Deciphering works when I load the code into node and give it the key/iv that Ruby uses to encipher the string. Has anyone got any idea what is going on?

EDIT

I've been trying to get this working in a number of ways. I've tried making the key a hex encoded string and a hex encoded char array, neither made any change. I'm really struggling with this as I am not a JS programmer, none of the stack exchange answers to other issues with cryptoJS seem to apply.

Comment: To clarify your your last sentence, you mean that if you use Node to encrypt the string, then this decryption works, but when Ruby encrypts the string decryption doesn't work? If so, this is probably a key-encoding (and IV-encoding) error. If you express your key as hex in both Ruby and Node, are they the same? I suspect one environment is parsing a hex-expressed key as a big hexadecimal number, while the other environment is reading individual ASCII or UTF-8 character values of the key string. (Or some similar confusion.)

Comment: (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19458437/710446)

Comment: @apsillers No, I output the key, iv and enciphered in irb and then paste them into the JS function in nodes repl. I have ensured the key, iv and message are the same in all environments.

Comment: @apsillers in addition, I have no output from the deciphering. The algorithm ends with the error thrown during the CryptoJS.AES.decrypt call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the cryptoJS source I discovered that I needed to include two more modules into my application.js the complete set of necessary js files was:

```
cryptoJS/components/aes
cryptoJS/components/core
cryptoJS/components/cipher-core
cryptoJS/components/mode-cfb
cryptoJS/components/pad-(whichever padding used)
```

the aes rollup did not work as it was missing some of these components so I feel it is best to include the components individually.